# What's the most efficient way of querying a collection parent models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to query a set of parents from a collection of records.
I have users messages that belong to conversations, My production DB has thousands of chat_messages and thousands of conversations, and I want to reduce the stress to both, my rails app and my MySQL database.

I currently have found 2 working methods to achieve this, using Rub's map function, and second, using 2 separate queries

Using Ruby's map method:

```
class Report
  # ...

  def conversations
    messages.map(&:conversation).uniq
  end

  # ...
end
```

Using 2 separate queries:

```
class Report
  # ...

  def conversations
    Conversation.where(id: messages.pluck(:conversation_id))
  end

  # ...
end
```

Both methods make my specs pass, however, performance is important to me so I'd like to prevent any crazy performance issues.

Comment: I would go with `Conversation.where(id: messages.select(:convsersation_id).distinct)` right now both of your methods are generating large arrays (one via `map` and the other via `pluck`) the above will simply generate a subquery as part of the where clause.

Comment: You could do `Conversation.joins(:messages).where("messages.report_id = ?", self.id)`

Comment: Also, I believe, `Conversation.joins(:messages).where(messages: {id: messages})`

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way to achieve this will be the following request:

`Conversation.where(id: messages.select(:conversation_id))`

`pluck` is faster than select when you use it with plain ruby or without to reuse the result of your `pluck`.

When you need to reuse result for an `ActiveRecord` query it's always better/faster to handle `ActiveRecord` collection.

But in both case I guess it will be always better than to use `distinct` which use a lot memory.